# DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging add as a reference

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I try to add the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging` reference in `Visual Studio 2012`. But if I go to "Reference" > "Add reference" there is not reference like this. I was googling the whole evening but still don't find it. Often I saw that I have to look at ".NET" tab in references. But there is no tab called ".NET". Can someone please help me to get out of this dumb situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Go to your `Solution Explorer` > right click on `references` and then click `Manage NuGet Packages`. Then search in tab "Online" for `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` and install it. After you can use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`.

Comment: Aaaaaah nice! Thank youu very much :) I will remember your answer with "NuGet" Packages if I got a problem like this :) Thank you guy!

Answer (score 1):

OfficeOpenXml and ExcelPackage is part of this package.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

Nu get: type in the below

Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml